# Insert an img tag into Canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to insert an image into a canvas element. Take this code for exemple (http://jsfiddle.net/n3L6e1wp/). I want to replace the text displayed in the canvas by an img tag.
I've tried to replace the content of the div by :

`<img src='<%= asset_path('layout/image.jpg') %>' id='picture' style='max-height:100%'>`

But nothing displays and I'm not even sure I can do this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you cant put images inside a `<canvas>`... you can draw them onto a canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canvas `drawImage` method will accept an html img element as an image source, so you can directly do this:

```
ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('picture'),0,0);
```

Example code and a Demo:

```js
window.onload=function(){
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('picture'),0,0);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<!-- src is for this demo. You can still use your <%...%> -->
<img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sun.png' id='picture' style='max-height:100%'>
```

Comment: Note you need to run that JS code when everything is loaded (or specifically the image element is loaded). so it needs to be wrapped in: `window.onload = function() { ... }`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yep, always wrap canvas JS code in `.onload` or in `$(function(){}`. Did you have an issue running the demo -- I thought Stack Snippets wrapped the JS in an onload automatically.

Comment: I also thought that, but yeah it seems to only be drawn after wrapping it in `onload` in Chrome at least. Perhaps the code is wrapped in a `document.ready` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, will work fine.

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas'),
var content = canvas.getContext('2d');

function insertImage() {
  image = new Image();
  image.src = 'assets/img.png';     //any img src
  image.onload = function(){
    content.drawImage(image, 300, 300);
  }
}

insertImage();
```

Comment: The thing is, I make my image change with JS. I have a form and when I load a picture, I'd like this picture to be drawn onto the canvas. This is why I was trying to keep my syntax. Perhaps there is another solution...

Comment: @Danny You can get the image `src` from the HTML page by doing: `document.getElementById('picture').src`.